# how to change the text background color dynamically in swiftui?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want change the text background color with passing function to the   .background()like this, the value of color is 0 or 1 or 2 will depend on the data of DB .how can I fix it:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var color = 0;
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .background(changeBkColor(int : self.$color))
        
            
    }
}
func changeBkColor(int : color)
{
    if(color == 1)
    {
        return Color.red;
    }
    else if(color == 2)
    {
        return Color.green;
    }
    else
    {
        return Color.blue;
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var color = 0;
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .background(changeBkColor(color: self.color))


    }
}
func changeBkColor(color: Int) -> Color
{
    if(color == 1)
    {
        return Color.red;
    }
    else if(color == 2)
    {
        return Color.green;
    }
    else
    {
        return Color.blue;
    }
}
```